# Select a OPTION in a SELECT with jQuery is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, web-standards

This is a weird issue, it works in IE but it doesn't in Firefox.

I have a `SELECT` control that when get focus, retrieve the `HTML` with the `OPTION`s in an `AJAX` call.

The onfocus event handler contains this code:

```
var selectedValue = $(":input[name='" + fieldName + "']").val();

var dataRetrieved = function(data)
{
    $(":input[name='" + fieldName + "']").html(data);
    $(":input[name='" + fieldName + "']").val(selectedValue);
    alert("data: " + data);
    alert("former value: " + selectedValue);
};

    $.post(url, data, dataRetrieved);
```

The first alert shows:

```
data: <option value=""/>
<option value="1" >a1</option>
<option value="2" >a2</option>
<option value="3" >a3</option>
```

And the second:

```
former value: 3
```

So it should work, actually it does in Internet Explorer (what make me think I'm doing something wrong about the HTML)

Any idea about what could be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input selector does not need a colon before it.  Your selector should look like this:

```
$("input[name='" + fieldName + "']")
```

not

```
$(":input[name='" + fieldName + "']")
```

That's my first guess as to why it might not be working.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/  That's what I saw in the documentation :P I've tried and it still does de same. Anyway, it's working on IE.

Comment: ":input" actually selects all the controls in the form (i.e. textareas, selects, buttons), not just inputs, so be careful when you use that.  What specifically isn't working?  Also, what does the code called by the ajax look like?

Comment: Good to know that :)  The code in the ajax call returns (at this point) always that HTML code. Basically, at the begining the server provides the SELECT with only one OPTION (the selected one in the database), but if you focus the control, the controls is filled with all the options. What I'm trying to arhieve, is store the current selected value, upload the control OPTIONS, and after that re-selected the former selection, that's what doesn't work in Firefox. Other thing I've realised, is that this issue only happens if I leave the dropdown open while it's getting the new HTML :(